# Unable to select drop down using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to scrape this website: http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/
I want to select "Jenjang" field, "SMA" value. After that, need to click "Cari Sekolah" button
[image]

Unfortunately, my code does not work. I manage to select SMA but then can't click "Cari Sekolah" to start the query. Anyone knows how to fix this. 
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')
webdriver = "/Users/rs26/Desktop/learnpython/web/chromedriver"
driver = Chrome(executable_path=webdriver, chrome_options=option)

url="http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)
select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("bentuk"))
select_element.select_by_value("SMA")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below solution to select from custom dropdown

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    # # Solution 1:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    element =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "select2-bentuk-container")))
    element.click()
    list=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='select2-search__field']")))
    list.send_keys("SMA")
    select=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-results__option")))
    select.click()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot unfortunately the send keys doesnt work. It managed to click the drop down but couldnt select SMA.

Comment: @rs26: what issue you are facing because I have already verified solution & its working fine for me

Comment: Thanks Dipak. Your code allows me to click the dropdown, but then it stops there and doesnt select "SMA". This is the error: WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Comment: Please try to copy entire solution it's a custom drop down we are sending input value SMA  and after that based on class name we are selecting it from list

Comment: Does it have to do with my chrome? the problem is: WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)

Comment: Yes it's a chrome driver issue download latest chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form button[type=submit]` css selector to click.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form button[type=submit]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks Sers. The problem is with the dropdown selection because the program stops there. The error is: WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
The submit button works fine on its own.